# guava multimap that uses TreeMap not HashMap?

Tags: java, guava

I have something like the following:

```
final SortedMap<Integer,List<Integer>> m = new TreeMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
```

And I'd like to use google-guava to make this a multimap. However I don't see any implementation that provides a SortedMap holding an ArrayList. I only see HashMap+ArrayList implementation (ArrayListMultimap). Does the implementation that I want exist?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Guava has a [TreeMultimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/TreeMultimap.html) that stores both keys and values in sorted order. However, this uses a `TreeSet` for the values rather than a `List` so it may not quite be what you want here. In that case, Guava allows you to create a `Multimap` that works any way you want using one of the `Multimaps.new*Multimap` methods, such as [Multimaps.newListMultimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#newListMultimap%28java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier%29). To make one that works like you describe, you'd just write this:

```
Map<Integer, Collection<Integer>> map = Maps.newTreeMap();
ListMultimap<Integer, Integer> m = Multimaps.newListMultimap(map,
    new Supplier<List<Integer>>() {
      public List<Integer> get() {
        return Lists.newArrayList(); // assuming you want to use ArrayList
      }
    });
```

Comment: ha...that's great, it's more verbose than the code it's intended to replace(!). Thanks though, I think I'll use it anyway.

Comment: @Kevin: The verbosity of creating it is minor compared to the savings in actually _using_ it. Plus, if you have to do this often you could create reusable suppliers for collection types you want to use.

Comment: And it will be a lot less verbose with Java 8, using constructor references : http://blog.cgdecker.com/2011/04/lambdas-in-java-constructor-references.html ;)

Comment: Wow, I totally forgot that I used the exact same example in that post. =P

Answer (score 7):

Here's how you can create that beast:

```
Multimap<Integer,Integer> multimap = Multimaps.newListMultimap(
    Maps.<Integer, Collection<Integer>>newTreeMap(),
    new Supplier<List<Integer>>() {
        public List<Integer> get() {
            return Lists.newArrayList();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Grrrr, Colin's answer wasn't there when I wrote this :-)

Comment: Upvoted for the one-liner :) (using explicit type argument specification for the newTreeMap() method call)